# generated column with condition sql

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql command to generate a column from other column according to condition

```
loan_amount | installment | start_date | status       
------------------------------------------------------------------  
500         | 100         | 2018-1-1   |
```

if (loan_amount % installment != 0) then  month_required to pay = loan_amount / installment + 1
else month_required = loan_amount / installment;

then i want to check by adding month_required to start_date if it has crossed current date. If not then status would generate "incomplete" else "complete" .

```
delimiter //

set @month = "0";

create trigger `status_check` before insert on `loan` 
for each row 
  begin 
    if NEW.loan_amount% NEW.installment != 0 
        then set @month NEW.loan_amount/ NEW.installment +1;
    else set @month = NEW.loan_amount/NEW.installment;

   end if ;

   if NOW() <= dateadd(NEW.start_date,INTERVAL @month MONTH) 
   then set NEW.status = "incomplete";
   else set NEW.status = "complete";
  end if;

end;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

what is the error here? please help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Comment: do you want to run it by hand once; to change your insert query to handle your case; or to put something that will do the maths for you for every update/ insert ?

Comment: Yes  i want something that will do the maths and will put "complete" or "incomplete" in status according to the result. I tried doing it with - " alter table add status varchar as (if(dateadd(month,month_required,start_date)>currentdate() , "complete","incomplete") .... i dont know how this kinda stuff work...

Answer (score 0):

I Can't make the real answer as you don't provide all your database field nor a data sample, but some `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` Trigger will probably do the job.

This is the base for the `BEFORE INSERT` :

```
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_test_insert`;
//

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_test_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.loan_amount % NEW.installment != 0 THEN
        SET NEW.month_required = NEW.loan_amount / NEW.installment + 1;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.month_required = NEW.loan_amount / NEW.installment;
    END IF;

END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Take a look at [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

And at :
[MYSQL Triggers - how to store the result of a calculated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151687/mysql-triggers-how-to-store-the-result-of-a-calculated-field)